# C# .NET System.Io.File.Move() does it guarantee file integrity on transfer?

Tags: c#, .net

For example, if I'm moving a file over FTP, I believe that does not guarantee file integrity, leaving me to do some sort of checking on file sender/receiver ( checksum for example ).

Can somebody tell me if the .net implementation of System.File.Move has any sort of file integrity checking if I'm moving a file across a network ( local network mind you, but a network still.. ). Checksum or anything?

Comment: [Does the CopyFile function verify that the data reached its final destination successfully?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120919-00/?p=6563/)

Comment: To my knowledge it is just the Move command that was part of DOS since 1.0. With all it's limitations. Soemthing like ROBOCOPY might be a better tool for this kind of work, but you may have to use consolerediction to get any usefull data from it.

Comment: It's just a wrapper around [`MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365239), which is entirely at the mercy of file system filters and drivers. So the short answer would be "no, it has no way of doing that in general".

Comment: FTP uses TCP/IP and TCP/IP does have checksums, so I'm pretty sure FTP also guarantees file integrity (as far as you can guarantee it). Of course no protocol can protect you from disk failure.

Comment: @Wazner: for what it's worth, the TCP/IP checksums are not very large, so errors can still happen. Granted, they are rare. In decades of using computer networks, I've only had one file transfer corrupt. But, there's a reason for crucial files people publish MD5 or SHA hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the protocol used to move the file.

Microsoft SMB protocol (most common protocol) does guarantee file integrity. It also supports file locking, meaning that someone else can not modify or partially read the file while the file is being moved/uploaded over the network.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx